# android.support.design.widget.NavigationView inflation issues (target api 23, min api 10)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-design

I am using eclipse and was previously using just android-support-v7-appcompt fine.  Targetting API 23 with min API 10.  I wanted to start update some of the UI so I grabbed the android-support-design library and decided to start with a NavigationView following along here (http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html ).

At first I was getting errors during inflation of of my main activity android.support.design.widget.NavigationView as it couldn't find a resource as I had the android.support.design library not targeting API 23.  I fixed that and now I'm at my latest error still during the same inflation which looks like it can't find android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView .

This is in the emulator running API 19 (api 23 intel emulator doesn't load for me last I tried).  I've added a bunch to pro-guard in all the projects (design, appcompat, my base library with my ndk/java mix code, top level project which builds my apk so I can have different apk's based on my data.

This has resulted many hours lost the last two days for no gain so far.  Both support libraries are up to date as of yesterday.  I'm still using eclipse as when I tried to convert to Android Studio months ago it ruined my entire directory structure and wouldn't build all my ndk libraries (there are a few) so I don't have time to look into Android Studio for a little while, not that it would help me here I assume.

My main activities start:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
....
```

Here is the printout of the stack trace caught

```
11-22 15:01:30.394: W/dalvikvm(4312): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuView; (1893)
11-22 15:01:30.394: W/dalvikvm(4312): Link of class 'Landroid/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuView;' failed
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at com.company.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     ... 22 more
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:97)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:165)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:94)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     ... 25 more
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.<app>.nyc-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.company.app.nyc-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
11-22 15:01:30.824: W/System.err(4244):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
11-22 15:01:30.834: W/System.err(4244):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
11-22 15:01:30.834: W/System.err(4244):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
11-22 15:01:30.834: W/System.err(4244):     ... 30 more
```

res/values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="divider">@color/divider</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>


<style name="SceneTheme" parent="AppTheme" >
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>

<style name="MenuTheme" parent="AppTheme" >
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

res/values-v21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary</item>

</style>

</resources>
```

Main Activty xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.company.app.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
    />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header_navbar"
    app:menu="@menu/action_navbar" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/location_drawer"
    android:name="com.company.app.LocationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_gravity="end" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

proguard.project.txt file i'm using in all projects

```
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize
-allowaccessmodification
-repackageclasses ''

-keep class com.company.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }

-keep class android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.app.** { *; }

-keep class android.support.v13.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v13.app.** { *; }

-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My min sdk version was higher than the libraries.  Changed the library and I was fine after I made sure everything else was added to the library and order/export list properly.

Comment: I've got the same problem. Unfortunately changing min sdk version didn't help for me.

Answer (score 9):

NavigationMenuView extends RecyclerView. I added recyclerview project into my workspace and this fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the **same version** for appcompat and design library in your gradle build file. Eg.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```